# Java: passing object implementing interface

Tags: java, objective-c, interface, parameter-passing, protocols

In Objective-C it is possible to pass a function parameter with type in the form `Object<Protocol>` which has the meaning "an object of type Object that implements the protocol Protocol". I was wondering whether there is a way to do the same in Java, for instance "an Android View that implements some custom interface" (protocol = java interface).

Comment: Very imprecise question

Comment: Yes, this is called "generics".

Comment: In Java there is no need for that. Just declare the parameter type as `X` which means “an object of whatever type that implements `X`” in case `X` is an interface.

Comment: In Objective-C, you can have a type that both is an instance of a type AND conforms to one or more protocols, like `MyClass<MyProtocol>`. Is that what you're asking about?

Comment: @newacct That's how I interpreted it.

Comment: @keyser: That's not how you interpreted it. You interpreted it to have something to do with generic type arguments, which it doesn't.

Comment: @newacct I suggested that a generic type parameter can be used to specify such restrictions. Is there a problem with specifying that something conforms to one or more protocols (interfaces) with a bounded type parameter?

Comment: @keyser: it's better now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use generics to specify that the parameter implements an interface:

```
public <T extends Protocol> void foo(T t) { ... }
```

This can be extended to specify multiple bounds. The type must be a subtype of all the specified types. `Object` isn't the best example, but here's how you could specify it:

```
public <T extends Object & Protocol> foo(T t) { ... }
```

Here's a related tutorial:

[Oracle Docs - Bounded Type Parameters](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/bounded.html)

Especially note this paragraph:

> To declare a bounded type parameter, list the type parameter's name,
>   followed by the extends keyword, followed by its upper bound, which in
>   this example is Number. Note that, in this context, extends is used in
>   a general sense to mean either "extends" (as in classes) or
>   "implements" (as in interfaces).

The unexpected part here is that `extends` is used for interfaces as well.

Note that you can get the desired behaviour without generics as well (see comments below):

```
public void foo(Protocol p) { ... }
```

since this allows for any object that *is-a* Protocol. If you want to specify multiple interfaces with this approach you could for example create a third interface that implements the other two. However, this assumes that you're in control of the classes that should be able to be passed as arguments since you need to implement that interface.

If you're passing a "regular" generic type parameter you simply specify the type directly:

```
public void foo(Object<Protocol> o) {
    // TODO: Implement
}
```

Comment: It’s worth noting that `<T extends Protocol> foo(T t)` adds exactly *no* benefit over simply using `foo(Protocol t)` as both methods do the same, they accept an arbitrary object which class implements `Protocol`. But the latter works since the very first Java release…

Comment: Lots of programming constructs are about readability rather than explicit benefits. It is worth noting though :)

Comment: Exactly, and `foo(Protocol t)` is *a lot more readable* than the unnecessary Generics construct.

Comment: I partly agree with you. Think of the other possibilities, and generalization. What if there are two interfaces?

Comment: @Holger I added the alternative to the answer itself to make it more complete

Comment: If you want to make it more complete you might add as well that you can use Generics to specify that a parameter should subclass `X` *and* implement `I` as `<T extends X & I> void foo(T t)`. That would solve the question in the way [newacct seems to interpret it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25286528/java-passing-object-implementing-interface/25286613?noredirect=1#comment39421558_25286528). Though I don’t know why someone downvoted your answer as the questioner has already accepted it.

Comment: Then we're on the same page. My point (in the question-comments) was that such things can be specified within generic type parameters. I'll extend the answer.

Comment: Creating a third `interface` extending two others is not the same as specifying the requirement of implementing the two interfaces via Generics. Think of `<T extends CharSequence&Serializable>`, here, `String` will fulfill the requirement while it won’t implement your custom interface `X extends CharSequence, Serializable`. In this scenario, using Generics is clearly the right thing to do.

Comment: Yes, of course. It assumes you're in control of the classes to be passed as arguments. I actually didn't think that far :p